# Laravel view product page not found

Tags: laravel

I have a problem, doing some product page, already got listen all products from database. And now doing view object page, to check currently product details. Doing everything by this video:
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpOaqDJ2D3A'

But it's not working for me. Writing page not found when I press to a link View product.

**1. I have created:** `view_object.blade.php`

**2. Have a controller:**

```
'public function view_brac( $BrackID )
    {
        return view('view_object');
    }'
```

**3. Have a route:**

```
'Route::get('view_object&(BrackID?)','BracController@view_brac');'
```

**4. And this is a link to View full object:**

```
'< a href="view_object& < ?php echo $ users->BrackID? >">Plačiau< /a >'
```

Can some you help, why this not working?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use URI with parameter like `view_object?brackId=5`, change the route to:

```
 Route::get('view_object', 'BracController@view_brac');
```

The controller method to:

```
public function view_brac()
{
    return view('view_object');
}
```

And the link to the view:

```
<a href="view_object?brackId={{ $users->BrackID }}">Plačiau</a>
```

Then you'll be able to get the `brackId` in a view or a controller method with:

```
{{ request('brackId') }}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect, thank you for your help :)

Comment: And I need now to show exactly that same selected object data from database, I have included line into my controller, it looks now: public function view_brac()
{   $Object = file::table('braclets')->where('BrackID' , '=' , '$BrackID')->get();
    return view('view_object', compact('Object'));
}  , but I'm getting an error with argument: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()" , so how I can get BrackID from Database where BrackID = BrackID selected?

Comment: `$object = \DB::table('braclets')->where('BrackID' , request('brackId'))->get()`

Comment: Thank you :) And one question, why need to use \ before DB?

Comment: Because you're working with query builder here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Answer (score 0):

First, you aren't returning anything in your controller method along with the view.

```
 public function view_brack( $BrackID )
 {
     $brack = Brack::find($BrackID);
     return view('view_object', compact('brack'));
 }
```

Second, the route definition is incorrect.

```
Route::get('brack/{brack}','BracController@view_brack')->name('brack.show');
```

Last, create your anchor tag using Laravel's helper functions.

```
<a href="{{ route('brack.show', $users->BrackID) }}">Plačiau</a>
```