# How to show selected product in the new page

Tags: database, laravel, object, view, get

I have done everything by this instruction:

[Laravel view product page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484695/laravel-view-product-page-not-found][1])

Everything works.

But now, when I'm selecting product from a list, click on it, and new window opens, I should see selected product details, but I'm getting an error:

> "Undefined variable: user (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Laravel\resources\views\view_object.blade.php)"

My `view_object.blade.php` looks:

```
<div class="header">
        @include('header')
    </header>
            <body>
                    <div class="content-products">
                        @foreach($user as $users)
                        <div id="myDiv">
                            <div class="products">
                                <img src="{{ $users->Image}}" alt="{{ $users->Title}}" width="200px" height="200px"><br>
                                {{ $users->Title}}<br>
                                {{ $users->Content}}<br>
                                {{ $users->Price}}€<br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>


            </body>
```

THis is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\file;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class BracController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('insertBrac');
    }

    public function showBrac()
    {
        $user=file::all();
        return view('apyrankes', compact('user'));
    }

    public function view_brac()
    {
        $object = \DB::table('braclets')->where('BrackID' , request('brackId'))->get();
        return view('view_object', compact('Object'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        {
        $user = new file;

        $user->Title= Input::get('title');
        $user->Content= Input::get('content');
        $user->Price= Input::get('price');
        if (Input::hasFile('image'))
            {
                $file=Input::file('image');
                $file->move(public_path(). '/uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());

                $user->Image = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            }

        $user->save();

        return redirect( "insertBrac" );

     }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code where you pass $users to the view

Comment: Everything you need to know: "Undefined variable: user" there is no such variable. Define it!

Comment: atleast you could have add your route definition with controller code.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@foreach($user as $users)
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="products">
        <img src="{{ $users->Image}}" alt="{{ $users->Title}}" width="200px" height="200px"><br>
        {{ $users->Title}}<br>
        {{ $users->Content}}<br>
        {{ $users->Price}}€<br>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

To

```
<div id="myDiv">
@if($user)
    <div class="products">
        <img src="{{ $user->Image}}" alt="{{ $user->Title}}" width="200px" height="200px"><br>
        {{ $user->Title}}<br>
        {{ $user->Content}}<br>
        {{ $user->Price}}€<br>
    </div>
@endif
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
public function view_brac()
{
    $object = DB::table('braclets')->where('BrackID' , request('brackId'))->first();
    return view('view_object', array('user' => $object));
}
```

Comment: "Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Laravel\resources\views\view_object.blade.php)"

Comment: Attach your controller to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your update, but after your changes, I'm getting an error: "Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Laravel\resources\views\view_object.blade.php)"

Comment: Show the migration for your `braclets` table

Comment: do you mean Model?

Comment: Do you have those exact names `Title`, `Image`, `Content`, `Price` in your `braclets` table ?

Comment: Yes, in my database table braclets exist fields: BrackID
Content
created_at
Image
Price
Title
updated_at

Comment: before the `return view('view_object'` in your controller, add `dd($object);` and show me the result

Comment: It means there is no `brack` with the request `brackId`. I have updated my answer again

Comment: I added an `if` condition before fetching the `object`

Comment: Yes, now it's working, no errors anymore. But I can get any product details, even when I select product with a picture, it show nothing, empty page

Comment: *can't get any details. Even when I select product with a photo , it shows me a empty page without any photo and details about product

Answer (score 0):

According to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484695/laravel-view-product-page-not-found)

1. You have to pass `user` from view, only one user

   ```
   public function view_brac( $BrackID )
   {
     $user = DB::table('tablename')->where('id',$BrackID)->first();
     return view('view_object')->with('user',$user);
   }
   ```
2. And display user deatils as, no need to use `foreach` to display single data

   ```
   <body>
   <div class="content-products">
       <div id="myDiv">
           <div class="products">
               <img src="{{ $user->Image}}" alt="{{ $user->Title}}" width="200px" height="200px"><br>
               {{ $user->Title}}<br>
               {{ $user->Content}}<br>
               {{ $user->Price}}€<br>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </body>
   ```

**Updated** 
After your updation

You have passed value as `Object` change it to `user`

```
public function view_brac()
{
    $user = \DB::table('braclets')->where('BrackID' , request('brackId'))->get();
    return view('view_object', compact('user'));
}
```

And be sure to use `viewAll` blade and `singleView` blade separately.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have done your changes, and I'm getting now an error: "Property [Image] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Laravel\resources\views\view_object.blade.php)"

Comment: did you change from `Object` to `user` ? Check variable name properly.

Comment: Yes, I have copy and paste everything you have shared

Comment: It's an issue with your User Model/Object.  Check that the User has an image property and that your spelling is consistent.  In the blade file, dd($user) and verify that the 'Image' property is present.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function view_brac()
{
    $object['user'] = \DB::table('braclets')->where('BrackID' , request('brackId'))->get();
    return view('view_object', compact('Object'));
  }
```

Try this code

Comment: Then I'm getting an error: Undefined variable: user